# how to use multiple variables in a file and use it in a command

Tags: bash, unix

I need help in writing a script in bash.

Basically i have one file which contains group names and group members

eq of the file
Group 1
Member1
Member2

Group 2
Member3
Member4
Member5
..

I would like to run them in a command like

```
command name Group 1 member.1 Member1, member.2 Member2,...
```

once it reaches empty row, move to

```
Group 2 member.1 Member3, ...
```

and so on until end of the file.

end result would be to list commands which can be executed later
name Group1 member.1 Member1, member.2 Member2
name Group2 member.1 Member3, member.2 Member4, member.3 Member4
name Group3 member.1 MemberX, member.2 MemberY,..

Not sure how to set the logic since I'm a beginner
Thank you

Comment: It is not clear from your question, where Group2 should be go. Is Group2 a command by itself? Make a small reproducible example for your problem.

Comment: Sorry, i edited my post to show end result

Comment: As for the logic, I would loop over the file, line by line, and collect each group into an array. When you come at the end of a group (i.e. an empty line), you run the command with the the array elements as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; FS="\n" }
{ printf("command name %s", $1)
  for (i = 2; i <= NF && $i; i++)
  { printf(" member.%s %s,", i - 1, $i) }
  print "" }' data
command name Group 1 member.1 Member1, member.2 Member2,
command name Group 2 member.1 Member3, member.2 Member4, member.3 Member5,
```

Why we have the test `i <= NF && $i` rather than just `i <= NF` is that because `\n` (newline) is the field *separator* `FS` and not a field *terminator*, the last record looks like it has an extra blank field. The last record is not followed by another record, and so the record separator `\n\n`  does not occur after its last field. Thus the terminating `\n` which occurs is interpreted as a field separator, resulting in an extra blank field.

EDIT: because the examples in the question end with `, ...`, I didn't follow any requirement whether commas are terminators or separators. This gets rid of trailing commas:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; FS="\n" }
{ printf("command name %s", $1)
  for (i = 2; i <= NF && $i; i++)
  { printf("%smember.%s %s", i == 2 ? " " : ", ", i - 1, $i) }
  print "" }' data
command name Group 1 member.1 Member1, member.2 Member2
command name Group 2 member.1 Member3, member.2 Member4, member.3 Member5
```

My usual go-to trick with separators is to write a condition that reacts to the first element; like the dummy variable `i` being zero, or in this case 2.

So that is to say, we regard the separators as being a prefix of each item. In a list like `a, b, c`, one way to look at it is that `c` lacks a trailing comma. But another way to look at it is that the first element `a` lacks a leading `,`  (comma + space). For all elements other than `a`, we first output `,`  and then the element.

I usually prefer this because `i == 0` is a nicer test than `i == n - 1`. In this case, it comes in particularly handy, because we have complex terminating condition `i <= NF && $i`, so that the last element isn't at the fixed index `NF`. But the first element is fixed.

Also, in situations in which the first element doesn't occur at a fixed index (like say we are filtering items from a list, and want them comma-separated) we can use a flag!

```
first = true;
for (i below number_of_fields)
{
  if (satisfies_condition(item[i])) {
    if (!first)
      print(", ");
    print(item[i]);
    first = false;   
  }
}
```

We cannot similarly have a flag which tells us which item is last; we have no way of knowing which item might be last, except in one special case.

Comment: @CentOS_ : You'll get a lot of background from [awk tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) . Good luck.

Comment: Looks good, the only thing it was adding was comma (,) at the end of the command, i've managed to remove it with sed. Thank you for the help. I'll look up more of awk for future.